# regex pattern replacing column value with one entry only

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I've successfully extracted the date pattern from the following column value example:

```
u"Message-ID: <18782981.1075855378110.JavaMail.evans@email> Date: Mon, 14 May 2001 16:39:00 -0700 (PDT) From: phillip.allen@email.com To: tim.belden@email.com"
```

Here is my code which did it:

```
enron_df['date'] = enron_df['message'].str.extract('Date:([^/]+)From:', expand=False).str.strip()
enron_df['date'] = enron_df['date'].str[5:-21][0]
enron_df['date'] = [x.encode('utf8') for x in enron_df['date']]
enron_df['date'] = enron_df['date'].str.replace(" ","-")
```

And here is example output:

```
enron_df.head(3)

            message sender  date
date            
2001-05-14  abcdefg allen   14-May-2001
2001-05-14  abcdefg bob     14-May-2001
2001-05-14  abcdefg john    14-May-2001
```

Is there a reason all rows beyond `head` are saving the same exact date? I'll drop the date column now that it's index but I need the index to show correctly.

They should be unique to every row...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second line of your code:

```
enron_df['date'] = enron_df['date'].str[5:-21][0]
```

is the reason for duplicating the same date in all rows. The `0` index selects the first row and then you set every date in the column equal to that value.

I believe removing the `[0]` would solve your problem.